# fluent-accordion different function on item and panel

Tags: javascript, html

When I add different function on item and title, click on item works fine but click on panel execute both function.
Is there a way to resolve that as I need click on item `Function_1` and click on panel `Function_2`

```
<fluent-accordion expand-mode="single">
        <fluent-accordion-item  *ngFor="let option of scope_summary" (click) = "Funcion_1(option.feedback)" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': option.color_code, 'position': 'relative'}">
            <span slot="heading" >
                {{option.display_name}}
                <span class="scope_badge" [ngStyle]="{'color': option.color_code}">
                    {{option.count}}
                </span> 
                
            </span>
            
            <div class="panel">
            <div *ngFor="let feedback of option.feedback" style="padding: 8px; overflow: auto; border-bottom: 1px solid gray;" (click)="Funcion_2(feedback)"> 
                <div *ngFor="let text of feedback.comments"
                 style="float: left; width: 85%;">{{text}}</div>
                <span [ngStyle]="{'background-color': option.color_code}"
                    style="float: left; width: 30px; height: 27px; text-align: center; font-size: 16px; margin-left: 8px; border-radius: 5px; padding-top: 4px;">
                    {{feedback.location.length}}</span>
            </div>
            </div>
        </fluent-accordion-item>
    </fluent-accordion>
```

i am trying to set different function in this code for item and different for panel click

Comment: event.stopPropagation() in the handler stops the event on an element bubbling up to a parent element. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation   Use this on the inner element's handler

Comment: Can you show us your javascript?

Comment: for now they looks like
public Function_1 = () => {

    Word.run(async (context)=> {
      console.log('Function_1')
    }
)}

public Function_2 = () => {

    Word.run(async (context)=> {
      console.log('Function_2')
    }
)}
and they are working, in case of click on Item i get 
Function_1
but in case of click on Panel i get
Function_2
Function_1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `event.stopPropagation()` in the inner element as Nikola Batinica said.
Inner your function

```html
<div *ngFor="let feedback of option.feedback" (click)="Funcion_2(feedback, event)"> 
</div>
```

```
Funtion_2(feedback: string, event: any) {
  event.stopPropagation()
  // rest of your logic
}
```

Comment: Nikola Batinica is the OP

Comment: and i am getting
Error: src/app/components/home/home.component.html:22:168 - error TS2339: Property 'event' does not exist on type 'HomeComponent'.

Comment: There is an asynchronous issue. Probably you need to set a setTimeout or put them after or before some logic. Another way could be to put it on the HTML as another click event: `(click)="event.stopPropagation()"`